# count with two left joins and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySQL books,betlines,matches.

```
books.bookId=betlines.bookId
betlines.bookId=books.bookId
matches.matchId=betlines.matchId
```

I want to connect them and filter for matches.leagueId=3 in order to see how many betlines for this specific league has each book.

```
SELECT name,books.bookId,COUNT(betlines.betlinesId) as total FROM books 
LEFT JOIN betlines on books.bookId=betlines.bookId 
LEFT JOIN matches on matches.matchId=betlines.matchId 
     AND matches.leagueId=3 
GROUP BY books.bookId;
```

the AND matches.leagueId=3 is not working as I have read in other answers (which have only one left join and maybe that is the problem) so this query returns the total betlines for each book and not only those betlines that belong to a match with leagueId=3.

What am I doing wrong?

this query doesn't show the books that have a total of zero values but filters correctly for the leagueId=3

```
SELECT name,books.bookId,COUNT(betlines.betlinesId) as total FROM books,betlines,matches 
WHERE matches.matchId=betlines.matchId 
AND matches.leagueId=3 AND books.bookId=betlines.bookId 
GROUP BY books.bookId;
```

Comment: You count from a column on the first join, not the second one

Comment: put it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to change the `COUNT()` to be from the `Matches` and not `BetLines`:

```
SELECT name, b.bookId, COUNT(m.matchId) as total
FROM books b LEFT JOIN
     betlines bl
     on b.bookId = bl.bookId LEFT JOIN
     matches
     on m.matchId = bl.matchId AND m.leagueId = 3 
GROUP BY b.bookId;
```

I added table aliases which make queries easier to write and to read.

As for your last query, it is using archaic `join` syntax that only supports inner joins.  You should use explicit joins, especially because you want `left join` in this case.

Comment: it's because I am archaic :) Unsure about which answer to vote because juergen and you posted the correct answer. (so newbie)